# Should I use xss_clean or htmlentities during form refill?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, xss

As the title says, I do refill my input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" value="<?= $this->input->post('my_input') ?>"/>
```

But is that safe? In accordance with CodeIgniter user guide, I can set the second parameter of the `$this->input->post()` to the `TRUE` and then the input will be filtered trough the `xss_clean` function, but is it really necessary? Or maybe I should just use `htmlentities()` function while doing that?

Comment: Did you try with xss_clean?  Was your application working with it?

Comment: @MaximeMorin Yes, but thats not what I'm asking...

Comment: On a comment lower, you said that `htmlentities` wasn't a good idea in your case.  That leaves xss_clean.  If you check [the source of xss_clean](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L297), you will see that it does a lot of clean up and strip some unwanted HTML tags.  If your application still works with it, that's the way I would go.  Hence why I asked, if it worked  with it... :)

Comment: @MaximeMorin The problem is that, when I type some text containing HTML in my field eg. `My car is <b>black</b>`, then while refill it would destroy te `<`, `>` tags by replacing them with `&lt;?`, `?&gt;` (xss_clean function doesnt the same job) , so it is really needed to filter the `$_POST` output with `htmlentities` or `xss_clean` in this case (form refill)?

Comment: That's exactly why I asked you if it worked with xss_clean.  From what I can read [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L436), it doesn't seems to remove the <b> tags.  So xss_clean could be the solution for you.  If it works, you got your answer.

Comment: @MaximeMorin For the HTML it is working, when I type `<script>alert();</script>` it does change the tags with the `|removed|` string, that why its called xss_clean I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Sanitize filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. But you havent answered my question(s).

Comment: It MAY be secure. It is an open-source application. Setting up global XSS filtering in application/config/config.php seems to be better way $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
but I strongly recommend to do some extra filtering.

Comment: What do you mean "it may" ? I'm asking , is its safe to display the raw post input content during the form refill. Instead of `$this->input->post('my_input');` I can use `$_POST['my_input']` so the CodeIgniter thing has nothing to do in this case, because in the first question I'm asking if I can display the post content (no matter if its Codeigniter input post, or the $_POST function.

Comment: You should never display the content of the $_POST directly. Using the built in XSS cleaner may clean the input, but it is an open source script, it is not your own code - you can not predict the result exactly until you know the cleaning process correctly (I don't). It is recommended to clean the data by yourself.

Comment: Ok, but usign the `htmlentities` isnt a good idea in my case, because when I want to use a `HTML` in my input.... it would destroy the tags and thats not the point of the refill job?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you output a string that you want to be considered as text into HTML markup, you must use an HTML-espacing function. I'd recommend `htmlspecialchars()` over `htmlentities()` for practical reasons but they're not qualitatively different. This is definitely the right thing to do for your quoted example code.

CI's `xss_clean` is a sanitisation function intended for input handling. Personally I think it's a shonky, misconceived bag of inconsistency that will mangle your input unnecessarily and cause weird bugs. But either way it's a defence in depth measure that does not absolve you from HTML-escaping.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a prep_for_form() function especially for that. I haven't looked through the code but that's where I would be looking if I were you.